# SIP SDK(without IPv6 support) integrated in iOS app... Does this app get approval from AppStore?

Tags: ios, app-store, ipv6, appstore-approval, pjsip

We have developed iOS app with 3rd party SIP SDK. This SIP SDK not integrated IPv6 support. If we upload our app to AppStore does this app get approval from AppStore?

This IPv6 support applies to only US or all other countries?

For ex in India Internet Service Providers(ISP) still running on IPv4. If I upload my iOS app to only in Indian market will it get approved by Apple AppStore?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about publishing to an "app store"  policies and procedures, rather than programming. See [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165)

Answer (score 3):

No, it will be rejected.

Their motivation is that your app may find itself in an IPv6 environment and it still must work at it best.

e.g. an IPv6 only corporate intranet in which your app can exit on internet through IPv6 to IPv4 device.